# Gradient border/drop shadow URP unity shader graph

Tags: unity, shaders, graph, unity-urp

I am using Unity Universal Render Pipeline and shader graphs in my game. Does anybody know how I would go about setting up a shader graph that adds a black gradient drop shadow/border with the game running underneath the effect like in this photo?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You don't need a shader graph for this. You could just make the black gradient an image, 9-slice it, and apply it as a UI panel in a Screen Space Overlay Canvas

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: If that solved your problem, want to walk through your solution in an Answer below?